# How to fuse wheel odom and visual odometry in robot_localization?

Tags: ros2, robot-localization

As the title says.

I have a question about robot localization.
I have a wheel robot and ZED2i camera in ROS2 humble.

My TF：robot_localization publish odom to base_link, rtabmap publish map to odom
Parameter：two_d_mode is true

My wheel odometer only has position and orientation without twist, so I use pose(x,y) and yaw and set different to true to merge with rtabmap's vo pose(x,y).

But when the robot faces the wall or is in a monotonous scene, my vo will be lost for a moment.
I have set odom0_pose_rejection_threshold, I will trust the wheel odom when it is lost.

However, after the vo is stable, I will continue to integrate the vo. At this time, it is also because the vo has been lost.
The pose is also not in the correct place, which also causes my fusion to be in the wrong position.

```
ekf_filter_node_local:

ros__parameters:

    use_sim_time: true

    frequency: 30.0

    sensor_timeout: 0.1

    two_d_mode: true

    transform_time_offset: 0.0

    transform_timeout: 0.0

    print_diagnostics: true

    debug: true

    debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

    publish_tf: true

    publish_acceleration: false

    reset_on_time_jump: true

    map_frame: map

    odom_frame: odom           

    base_link_frame: base_link

    world_frame: odom

    odom0: turtle_odom

    odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                   false, false, true,
                   false,  false,  false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
    #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
    #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
    #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
    #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]

    odom0_queue_size: 10

    odom0_nodelay: true

    odom0_differential: true

    odom0_relative: true

    odom0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    odom1: rtabmap/odom

    odom1_config: [true, true, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  true, true, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  true,  false,  false]
    #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
    #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
    #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
    #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
    #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]

    odom1_nodelay: true

    odom1_differential: false

    odom1_relative: true

    odom1_queue_size: 7

    odom1_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.1

    odom1_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.1

    odom1_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.1

    odom1_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    stamped_control: false

    control_timeout: 0.2

    control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

    acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

    deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

    acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

    deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

    process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
                               
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, I'm working on a tutorial for that right now.

Show us your R_L config file. What is your specific problem? It sounds like you're doing the right thing with the rejection threshold, perhaps you didn't set it low enough? Or are you saying that its not coming back after being rejected?

Comment: I've updated the R_L config file in my post.

The problem I encountered is： the rtabmap algorithm exceeds the setting of odom1_pose_rejection_threshold at a certain time, which means that rtabmap is not accurate.

When rtabmap is lower than the setting of odom1_pose_rejection_threshold, Robot_Localization believes in rtabmap's pose(x,y ).

What I mean is that the raw data when my rtabmap faces the wall or has few features is no longer accurate. Is there any way I can use robot_localization to fusing vo and wheel odom to improve it?

Thank you! Tim

Comment: Fuse the odometry X and Y velocities only, not the poses. Turn off differential. Tune covariances to be proportational to your confidence in that measurement. For VO, decrease your confidence in the XY pose significantly.

Comment: Because my odometry has no velocities, I enable differential. Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's just being used for the `odom` frame, is there any reason not to fuse your wheel encoder odometry absolutely and turn on `_differential` mode for your VO data? I'd make the more stable input the pose source, and use the less stable one as a velocity.